# Utilizando o Entity Framework é possível ter um Relacionamento One-to-Many sem utilizar uma coleção?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Utilizando as seguintes classes abaixo, possuo um relacionamento One-to-One porém como possui duas propriedades para a mesma classe o entity tem um erro ao gerar as migrations

```
public class Glass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? LeftSideId {get;set;}
    public Side LeftSide {get;set;}
    public int? RightSideId {get;set;}
    public Side RightSide {get;set;}
}

public class Side
{ 
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string  Value {get;set;}
    public int Glass {get;set;}
    public Glass Glass {get;set;} 

}
```

Mapeamento utilizando o Fluent-API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Side>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(side => side.Glass)
        .WithOne(glass => glass.LeftSide)
        .HasForeignKey<Glass>(glass => glass.LeftSideId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehaviour.ClientSetNull);

    entity.HasOne(side => side.Glass)
        .WithOne(glass => glass.RightSide)
        .HasForeignKey<Glass>(glass => glass.RightSideId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehaviour.ClientSetNull);
});
```

Erro gerado:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'Side.Glass' and 'Glass.RightSide
> ', because there already is a relationship between 'Side.Glass' and
> 'Glass.LeftSide '.   Navigation properties can only participate in a
> single relationship.

Existe alguma solução elegante para este cenario? Talvez utilizar um One-to-Many mas sem usar coleção?

Comment: Só se fosse uma coleção de `Sides` no `Glass` e dentro do `Side` houvesse a informação da `Direction`. Ou tivesse um `Glass2` dentro do `Side`, mas aí ficaria bem feio.

Comment: Adotei essa solução, criando uma lista, e cada item tem um enumerador, e criei um indexer na classe para buscar o item por essa enumeração

Answer (score -1):

Para mapear de forma correta esse modelo de negócio precisa que a classe `Side` tem duas enumerações da classe `Glass` simbolizando a relação de 1 para muitos da seguinte forma:

```
public class Side
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Value { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Glass> GlassLeftSide { get; set; } = new();      
    public virtual ICollection<Glass> GlassRightSide { get; set; } = new();
}
```

---

```
public class Glass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public int? LeftSideId { get; set; }    
    public int? RightSideId { get; set; }    
    public virtual Side LeftSide { get; set; }    
    public virtual Side RightSide { get; set; }
}
```

e nas suas configurações de mapeamento:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Glass>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.LeftSide)
        .WithMany(p => p.GlassLeftSide)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.LeftSideId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Glass_Side_Left");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.RightSide)
        .WithMany(p => p.GlassRightSide)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.RightSideId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Glass_Side_Right");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Side>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Value)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsUnicode(false);
});
```

***Referencias:***

- [Entity Framework documentation hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)
- [Getting Started with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli)
- [One-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many)

Comment: ?Levar voto negativo do que está certo é bem complicado?